# Что означает слово после двоеточия в заголовке функции

Tags: php

Объясните, что означает эта запись?

```
public function addErrors(array $errors): bool {}
```

А точнее, что идет после скобок и где можно подробней об этом узнать и почитать?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations

Comment: Это значит что вызываемый метод должен вернуть логический тип данных

Comment: Это значит функция возвращает булево значение т.е из True и False,{} - это тело функции,php давно занимался,сейчас в основном Python,там есть такое(прям в код можно писать для Python 3) def func(my_var:int)->float,значит принимает целое,возвращает дробное,для безтиповых ЯП это как бы псевдокод,чтобы логику понимать и чтобы в runtime ошибок не было.

Comment: @Константин, в Python - это не типизация от слова совсем, аннотациями могут быть любые объекты и не используются в runtime

Comment: Я имел ввиду в runtime для самокотроля, чтобы прогу лучше понимать.Можно сделать так что бы аннотации проверялись через instanceof и будет типизированный язык)Двоеточие это как бы математическая запись.

Answer (score 2):

Краткая выдержка из мануала [Возврат значений](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.returning-values.php):

> В PHP 7 добавлена возможность объявлять **тип** возвращаемого
> значения. Аналогично объявлению типов аргументов можно задать тип
> значения, которое будет возвращаться функцией. Типы, которые можно
> объявить для возвращаемых значений те же, что и для аргументов
> функций.
>
> В режиме **слабой типизации** по умолчанию возвращаемые значения будут
> приводиться к корректному типу, если они еще не относятся к этому
> типу. Если это преобразование типа не разрешено, будет выброшена ошибка
> **TypeError**.
>
> При **строгой типизации** возвращаемое значение должно быть заданного типа, иначе
> будет выброшено исключение **TypeError**.

Короче говоря, это новая фишка в PHP 7 и выше, можно явно указать тип возвращаемого значения, чтобы поведение функции было более предсказуемым. Принцип тот же, что и при объявлении типов входных параметров.

Answer (score 1):

Это тип возвращаемого значения. То есть этот метод обязательно должен вернуть булевое значение - `true` или `false`